# Create a rule to flag out certain texts in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an input cell that has many countries e.g. America, Bahamas, Canada, Denmark, England, France, etc. Suppose I want to have a cell which returns 1 when there is America or Bahamas in the input cell and 0 when there is neither America or Bahamas in the input cell. How do I  do this?

Comment: *America* isn't a country. In fact, with varying added descriptors it could be one of two continents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **A1** contains **only one** country, then

```
=ISNUMBER(FIND("America",A1))+ISNUMBER(FIND("Bahamas",A1))
```

If **A1** can contain a **list of** countries, then:

```
=MIN(ISNUMBER(FIND("America",A1))+ISNUMBER(FIND("Bahamas",A1)),1)
```

[image]

Comment: `=SIGN(ISNUMBER(FIND("America",A1))+ISNUMBER(FIND("Bahamas",A1)))` works as well.